# Use Gretty plugin instead of Jetty for Gradle 4.2.1

Tags: java, maven, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using LibGDX to make a videogame and I updated Android Studio to version 3 and Gradle to version 4 without noticing that some of the plugins that LibGDX uses on the Gradle files are now deprecated.

I have no experience using Gradle and I know a little bit about how the tasks work and the plugins but not in much depth.

My question is about the Jetty plugin that is now deprecated and Gradle recommends me to use the Gretty plugin instead.

I already put it in my code but, of course, now I need to change the Jetty tasks for the Gretty ones and that is now my problem.

This is my build.gradle file right now:

```
apply plugin: "java"
//apply plugin: "jetty"
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

//TODO: Arreglar jetty por gretty

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.6.0' // Should match the gwt version used for building the gwt backend
    maxHeapSize="1G" // Default 256m is not enough for gwt compiler. GWT is HUNGRY
    minHeapSize="1G"

    src = files(file("src/")) // Needs to be in front of "modules" below.
    modules 'com.projectcastle.game.GdxDefinition'
    devModules 'com.projectcastle.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev'
    project.webAppDirName = 'webapp'

    compiler {
        strict = true;
        enableClosureCompiler = true;
        disableCastChecking = true;
    }
}

task draftRun(type: JettyRunWar) {
    dependsOn draftWar
    dependsOn.remove('war')
    webApp=draftWar.archivePath
    daemon=true
}

task superDev(type: de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.GwtSuperDev) {
    dependsOn draftRun
    doFirst {
        gwt.modules = gwt.devModules
    }
}

task dist(dependsOn: [clean, compileGwt]) {
    doLast {
        file("build/dist").mkdirs()
        copy {
            from "build/gwt/out"
            into "build/dist"
        }
        copy {
            from "webapp"
            into "build/dist"
            }
        copy {
            from "war"
            into "build/dist"
        }
    }
}

draftWar {
   from "war"
}

task addSource << {
    sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += files(project(':core').sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
}

tasks.compileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)
tasks.draftCompileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-html"
}
```

And this is the error is giving me:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':html'.
> Could not get unknown property 'JettyRunWar' for project ':html' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

So the `JettyRunWar` type and the `draftRun` task are the ones that I don't know how to change to make them compatible for Gretty.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this build file gets rid of jetty completely (you just have to edit some lines so it fits your project):
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-gwt/build.gradle

But there is another huge problem with gradle 4.+ as seen in this issue:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698

They say they will fix it and as long as they are working on it, we have to use old gradle and had to wait.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will then downgrade my AS and Gradle. Also, I will get rid of Jetty to not have this problem later in the future

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (maybe you deleted it when updating Gradle from 2.X version) you deleted import of Jetty but in

> html/build.gradle

you should delete its starter too:

> task draftRun(type: JettyRunWar) {
> dependsOn draftWar
> dependsOn.remove('war')
> webApp=draftWar.archivePath
> daemon=true }

and probably you should delete starter in the same file:

> task superDev(type: de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.GwtSuperDev) {
> dependsOn draftRun
> doFirst {
> gwt.modules = gwt.devModules
> } }

cheers!